# Can kafka streams state store be used for debouncing events?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a particular use case wherein I want to wait for a few seconds to capture similar messages and send the latest one.

I'm going through this book - Kafka Streams in Action by William P. Bejeck Jr.

[image: Kafka streams state store]

The above image shows that we can store state in local state store, can I use this statestore to store a message and wait for a window of 5 secs to see similar messages and just send the latest one?

If yes, will the other messages(which are not similar to current one) have to wait until the current messages window of 5 secs is over - will the processing of other messages which are coming to the stream be stopped?

Comment: The book also goes over windowing, by the way, which sounds like what you're asking

Comment: It goes over windowing for "joins", I'm not sure whether it is allowed with local state store. If yes - are other messages which are different from the current message, processed or they have to wait for 5 secs until the current message is processed?

Comment: I think that depends on which type of window you use